# Can't install libpng-dev and libtiff5-dev

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to work with tesseract-ocr to read some text in a photo in a program but when I try to follow their instructions on how to [install](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#linux) I keep getting errors trying to run

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev
```

They both do something similar:

```
$ sudo apt install  libpng-dev  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  libpng-tools  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  libpng-dev libpng-tools  
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
Need to get 203 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 703 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libpng-dev amd64 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1  
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libpng-tools amd64 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1  
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libpng-dev amd64 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::17 80]  
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 libpng-tools amd64 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::17 80]  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng1.6/libpng-dev_1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::17 80]  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng1.6/libpng-tools_1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::17 80]  
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

When I try to follow the links it looks like it's just looking for the wrong versions.  How can I make it look for the correct ones?

Comment: Have you `sudo apt update` to update your machine's software repositories lists (ie. list of software packages & versions available)

Comment: That fixed it.  If you make an answer Ill mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention

> it looks like it's just looking for the wrong versions

so update your machine's software repository lists with the command

```
sudo apt update
```

This will update the lists of software packages available (including versions) available for sources listed for your machine (sources found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` & `sources.list.d/`)